# Adding data to queue from multiple processes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to call the same process multiple times and capture the return

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    #Call processes here.
    var1 = 100000000
    var2 = 1000000
    var3 = 100000

    q = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=call_pool, args=(q,var1))
    p2 = Process(target=call_pool, args=(q,var2))
    p3 = Process(target=call_pool, args=(q,var3))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()

    print q.get()    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"

def call_pool(queue,var):
    #Call pool here
    queue.put(len(pool_gen(var)))


def pool_gen(var):
    pool = Pool()
    data = pool.map(f, range(var))
    return data

def f(x):
    return x*x*x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    main()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

I dont think there is an append function for the queue.
Do i need to define 3 queues and put data in 3x over?

Comment: I have an i9-9900k running this code, 16 threads @5GHz, and if I run this with queue, I get a return in 18 seconds, if I run with manager, I get return in 28 seconds. If I run it with just a print statement in the call_pool function, I get a reply on 15 seconds. Is there a way to make manager run faster?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer was to use managers...

```
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    #Call processes here.
    var1 = 100000
    var2 = 100000
    var3 = 100000

    manager = Manager()
    d = manager.list()

    p1 = Process(target=call_pool, args=(d,var1))
    p2 = Process(target=call_pool, args=(d,var2))
    p3 = Process(target=call_pool, args=(d,var3))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()

    print d    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"

def call_pool(d,var):
    #Call pool here
    d.append(len(pool_gen(var)))


def pool_gen(var):
    pool = Pool()
    data = pool.map(f, range(var))
    return data

def f(x):
    return x*x*x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    main()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

Comment: I have an i9-9900k running this code, 16 threads @5GHz, and if I run this with queue, I get a return in 18 seconds, if I run with manager, I get return in 28 seconds. If I run it with just a print statement in the call_pool function, I get a reply on 15 seconds. Is there a way to make manager run faster?